# SSL Error - Unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We are using nginx. I am trying to access an API  using Postman in my application and I am getting Unable to verify the first certificate issue

I have configured my ssl keys as follows

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/******.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/******.key;
```

I don't have any intermediate certificate. Only one certificate I am provided.

My application is working properly on other browser activities. https is enabled and no warnings on browser triggers.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: This sounds like a Postman CA certificates issue.  If browsers work fine, then review and export the Intermediate CAs and Trusted Root CA certificates, then create a PEM file and assign it to Postman [using these instructions](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/).

Answer (score 0):

you need create a new .crt file with the content of your .crt + the content of your bunble.crt and tell nginx to use that new one, Regards and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem with do this

```
cat ***.crt ***-bundel.crt > ****.crt
```

after that set this new file instead of previous ***.crt file in **Nginx** config file.
in my scenario i have ***.crt file and another file*** -bundel.txt like  this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
******
******
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
******
******
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and not included ***.crt file.
after concat these two files solve the issue.